# Error when trying to alter column type from text to geometry

Tags: postgresql, matlab

I have a table in a `postgres` database that I uploaded from `Matlab`. Since Matlab does not know the geometry type I couldn´t upload the corresponding column with the hex strings as geometry type data and uploaded them as text. When I now try to alter the column type to geometry by using the code below I get an error message.

```
Alter Table data_table alter column geom type geometry;
```

> ERROR:  Invalid hex string, length (1107477) has to be a multiple of
>   two! SQL state: XX000

Comment: I am new with the geometry type but : first you need postgis extension. And second : I think you will have to code/find something to convert your string collection from matlab to a geometry collection.I do not think that postgis can do it natively.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this : https://postgis.net/docs/Populate_Geometry_Columns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the `geometry` input function expects the string to be in EWKB format, where each byte is represented by two hexadecimal digits. Obviously the data are not in that format.

If you know how to convert the data, you can use

```
ALTER TABLE data_table
ALTER geom TYPE geometry
   USING some_function(geom);
```

Here `some_function` stands for a function or expression that does the conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You were right the hex code was somehow not correct. I retrieved the data via select into Matlab and just noticed that doing so the data are somehow not the same any more. I checked it using qgis and using the data out of the database itself it worked as supposed but when I just copied the same hex code from what was downloaded in Matlab it gave me the same error as before. Does anybody know how to solve that issue? Is it possible that the hex code is just too long? Because apparently when I download point geometries it still works.

Comment: Also I noticed that it depends on the connection type to the database. When I just JDBC instead I didn´t receive a string containing the hex code, but PGobjects. But then I get the problem that I can´t upload those object to the postgres database with sqlwrite. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, since I have no idea of Matlab. You have to get these geometries into a format that PostGIS understands.

Comment: I fixed it. Even though I still don´t know why the values were altered.